# How do I upload an entire directory to S3?

Tags: python, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want my directory, and all its sub directories and files, to go straight to S3. Clone it.

Is there an easy script/program to do that?

I'm on Ubuntu linux.

Comment: Did you read s3cmd's manpage? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/s3cmd.1.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Install S3 (http://s3tools.org/download)
2. Configure it:
   `s3cmd --configure`
3. Create a bucket: `s3cmd mb s3://my-bucket` (alternatively, you can do this via a tool like S3Fox)
4. Sync your local directory with S3: `s3cmd sync /path/to/local/dir/ s3://my-bucket`